# overflow-x stacks divs on window resize

Tags: html, css, resize, overflow

I would like to setup a horizontal container that holds multiple (smaller) columns within it. I have the following setup:

http://jsfiddle.net/f464W/1/

As you can see, when you resize the window, the .column containers just stack vertically when the width of the window is too small to contain them all.

Shouldn't

```
overflow-x: hidden
```

Stop the .column class from being displayed when they run off the side of .container?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `white-space: no-wrap` the `.container`

http://jsfiddle.net/feitla/f464W/17/

```
.container {
    max-height: 600px;
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 100px;
    background: red;
    padding: 0;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Comment: Nailed it. Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 1):

With `overflow-x: hidden` will hide what exceeds on the right of your `div`. But the natural behaviour of the `div`s are to wrap to the line below when they're out of space, therefore nothing exceeds.
You need to make the `div`s not wrap. if you add `white-space: nowrap` to your container CSS they will only stack horizontally.

Answer (score 0):

You can add `float: left;` to `.column` and that should give you the desired effect. You'll then have to play with `margin` if you want to maintain the spacing you had between the columns.